# How to enable Intellisense for Classic ASP in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp-classic, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to get Intellisense for classic ASP for Visual Studio 2015, and still have html and JavaScript formatting/Intellisense? I tried adding an extension and using html forms but it seems to not detect <% and %> tags.

Comment: Has that change from Visual Studio 2013? http://itanswers.xyz/question/30971440/how-to-enable-intellisense-and-syntax-highlighting-for-classic-asp-in-visual-stu   From main menu: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension
add extension "ASP" and select Automatic Editor Selector (XML) and press add

Comment: That doesn't let you have classic asp intellisense along side html/javascript, they don't appear to be compatible.

Comment: Time has moved on and you may likely be using VS Code now. It has a good extension called "Classic ASP" (currently on v0.0.4).